# Padding a numeric display in WPF

Tags: wpf, string, ivalueconverter, formatter

I've got a position readout that's very simple -- it's just a TextBlock with a Style applied to it.  In that Style, I just set it like so (there are more properties than this, but I took them out for conciseness):

```
    <Style x:Key="NumberStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
```

Now, I have one display that uses this style, and it will display a number from 0.0 to 30000.0.  The problem is that since I'm centering the text, the number (if changing rapidly) jumps all over the place and it's a little disturbing.  I'd like to format my string so that it won't do this.

I tried this ConverterParameter in XAML:

```
ConverterParameter='\{0:00000.0\}'
```

and while it does the padding properly, I'll get numbers like 00032.5.  I then replaced the `0` with `#`, but that ends up behaving just like `{0:0.0}`.  I looked at the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and didn't see anything else that would help.

The only thing I can come up with is that I'd have to write a new IValueConverter to do this.  In other words, in the Convert() method, I would have to take `parameter` and parse it for my own special character.  And then when I detect this, replace the missing numbers with spaces.

However, what I am really trying to learn here is, can this be done by simply using a different character in the format string that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `{}{0,10:#,0}` for a field of 10 characters.

Note, however, that this will give odd results if the font is not fixed-width. I tried it in [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/), and it works, but the text doesn't line up with a proportional font.

Comment: not sure what the {} in front is for?  I assume that's a typo, since that produces a compiler error...

Comment: It escapes the format parameter in a WPF Binding markup extension, where the '{' character begins a new markup extension. I'd thought you were using it in a markup extension; if not, just remove them.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like `{0,7}` (display argument on seven positions, padding to the left with spaces). However, even in this case, for the text not to jump, you need to use a monospaced font, or at least a font that has the width of the space character equal to the width of the digits.