# Add leading 0 in the textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a textbox, the maxlength is 10. What I want is to add leading 0's to the text.

For example:

```
    input 1,         then 0000000001
    input 12,        then 0000000012
    input 123,       then 0000000123
```

I tried [Padding a numeric display in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599260/padding-a-numeric-display-in-wpf)

It is not working and I don't want to use code behind text changed event. I'd prefer pure xaml.

**UPDATED:**

The code is simple. Something like

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Info,StringFormat={}{0:0000000000}}" MaxLength="10" />
```

It shows `0000000000` in the first place, then you can't input the 11th letter to let the byte shift to the left afterwards.

Comment: The question that is linked only uses XAML. What is not working?

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Comment: I know how to achieve this. But first share what you have done so that i can understand your bind and etc.

Comment: Okay. The thing is, I follow the link. Somehow like this, it display `0000000000` at the beginning since I set the MaxLength is 10. Then I can't input any number anymore. I think the link did't have  `MaxLength` in the textbox.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, see my updated code.

Comment: So the actual problem is that you expect the numbers to shift left and they don't.  If so, that is not available out of the box.

Comment: Yes, maybe a converter must show up.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you binding a int type property to `TextBox.Text`, all you need to do is setting `Binding.StringFormat` correctly.

```
<TextBox Text={Binding path to you int property, StringFormat=d10}/>
```

Comment: I have MaxLength="10" in the textbox. Your code is not working unfortunately.

Comment: @Bigeyes Not working? So you must set `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` to `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` then. Change it to `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` will definately work.

Comment: Works well, even validates the length of the input. Thanks!